# Autofill username into web view

Tags: swift, uiwebview

The web view first loads a url to a login page. When the user logs in for the first time and selects the checkbox to remember the username, save the username to core data. When the user logs in again, autofill username text field for the username stored in core data.

How would this be done in Swift?

Comment: What have you done so far? This isn't a specific question; it's rather broad. Narrow it down to a specific question, rather than asking us to develop an entire app for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user firsts signs in you need to listen to

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

Here you can get the post data, which should contain the username, password, and remember username values. Check if the remember username is checked and then save the username to core data.

When the user logs in any other time, use this `webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)` to fill in the username text field.

You can do this by using the `webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: String)`

You'll need to use some javascript and it should be something like this.

```
document.getElementByID('id of the username text field').value = username
```

So for your website, your delegate methods should look like this.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    if let url = webView.request?.url {

        if url.absoluteString == "https://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm" {

            // Autofill the username and password here.

            webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('username').value = \"username\"")

            webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('label2').value = \"password\"")
        }
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if let url = webView.request?.url {

        if url.absoluteString == "https://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm" {

            // Get the username and password here.

            let username = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('username').value")

            let password = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('label2').value")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: https://retail.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm this is my url how to try for this ?? @Tristan Beaton

Comment: thnk you. @Tristane Beaton  >  I will try this n inform u is it working or not.

Comment: In Swift 4, remember to implement WKNavigationDelegate

Comment: @Tristan Beaton, is it possible to apply same way this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71572952/13614484